# Odd TestObserver behaviour when subscribing to a Subject

Tags: java, kotlin, rx-java, rx-java2

Consider the following *RxJava 2* snippet in *Kotlin*:

```
// 1. Create subject
val subject = PublishSubject.create<Int>()

// 2. Get observable
val observable = subject.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())

// 3. Subscribe
val observer = observable.test()

// 4. Trigger next
subject.onNext(42)

// 5. Await
observer.awaitCount(1)

// 6. Assert value
observer.assertValue(42)
```

From my understanding, `observer` should be able to receive `42` after waiting on statement **5** and the assertion on statement **6** should succeed.

However, what actually happens is: **5** blocks until it times out because no value is received and the assertion on **6** fails.

Also, if I put a breakpoint on **3** and just resume the execution after it pauses, everything will work. Looks like a threading problem.

I'm clearly missing something here. What would be the correct way to consume a hot observable?

Comment: You are right. I'll edit the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By unsing `subscribeOn`, you put the actual subscription to the `Subject` on another thread which then may take a bit longer so that `subject.onNext(42)` still finds an unsubscribed `Subject`.

Apart from the fact that using `subscribeOn` on a `PublishSubject` has no practical use, you could await the subscription by looping a bit:

```
while (!subject.hasObservers()) { Thread.sleep(1); }
```

Comment: This makes sense, although I confess I'd expect subscriptions and emissions to be synchronised internally. In my particular case, I don't have control over **1** and **2**. I'm just consuming a hot observable provided by an external library which happens to be emitting on IO scheduler threads. Before I mark your answer as accepted, do you think there would be a better way to accomplish this without the weird `while` loop?

Comment: By having 2, the API provider has explicitly opted out of any sychnronized behavior, thus you have to make him/her not do `subscribeOn`.